# Custom directive on schema stitching

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js

i'm trying to add a directive to a type that extends one from a remote schema.

```
   const extensionSchema = `
    directive @upper on FIELD_DEFINITION
    extend type User {
        firstname: String @upper
    }

`;
    // resolvedSchemas is an array of makeRemoteExecutableSchema coming from introspection queries.
resolvedSchemas.push(extensionSchema);

return mergeSchemas({
    schemas: resolvedSchemas,
    schemaDirectives: {
        upper: UpperCaseDirective
    }
   })
```

And i get: `Error: Unknown directive "upper".`.
What am i missing?

My directive:

```
const { SchemaDirectiveVisitor } = require("graphql-tools");
const { defaultFieldResolver } = require("graphql");

module.exports = class UpperCaseDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
    field.resolve = async function (...args) {
            const result = await resolve.apply(this, args);
            console.log("RESULTADOOOO", result);
      if (typeof result === "string") {
        return result.toUpperCase();
      }
      return result;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this question is super old, but here i go anyway; are you adding the merged schemas to your makeExecutableSchema or whatever schema youre passing to your apollo-server constructor? (im assuming this is with apollo server... Where are you getting the mergeSchemas function?